# C# XmlSerialization: Adding a wrapper

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, .net-3.5

I am changing the approach of serializing data inside my application. Until now I did everything manually, which created a lot of code, but also granted me a lot of flexibility.

Now I am using the `XmlSerializer`, and created a DataTransferModel in order to provide the data in the way I want.

The only thing that is getting in my way now is that I need to have a wrapper around the XML-Content. It is just an other tag containing the name of the application. How can I add this tag around the XML-Documents created inside the application?

Thanks and if you need more information do not hestiate to ask.

EDIT: The tag should be the first tag in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved this problem using a custom method that changes the `XmlDocument` as I wish.

I basically created a method that "prepares" the `XmlDocument`, adding a the wrapper-Tag around the original one. This method can be called every time before I have to use the `XmlDocument`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Prepares the document to export it.
    /// Adds the Wrapper tags
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contentDocument">The Document to prepare.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the prepared document.</returns>
    private static XmlDocument PrepareExportDocument(XmlDocument contentDocument)
    {
        XmlDocument returnDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlNode rootElement = returnDoc.CreateElement("Wrapper-Tag");

        XmlNode importedNode = returnDoc.ImportNode(contentDocument.DocumentElement, true);

        rootElement.AppendChild(importedNode);

        returnDoc.AppendChild(rootElement);

        return returnDoc;
    }
```

If you have better approaches, or you feel this approach is not correct feel free to comment or add your own answers. For now I will mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You add a wrapper element by adding another layer to the object-model; `XmlSerializer` is *generally* a mirror of the objects. So; if you want a root `<MyApp>` element, then add that:

```
[XmlRoot("MyApp")]
public class SomeWrapper {
    public YourExistingModel SomeName {get;set;}
}
```

and serialize a `SomeWrapper` instead of a `YourExistingModel`.

Comment: There are quite some classes that are being serialized. Would this kind of wrapper work generically for all classes I want to serialize? Can I use YourExistingModel to reference different type of classes (generically)?

Comment: @ElMac that depends on whether you want them all to have the same root element name and next-level element name... are the names common?

Comment: The root element should always be the same. The next element could be for example "Settings" or "Content" etc.

Comment: @ElMac then I strongly recommend different root types. You can do it with a generic type, but it would involve `XmlAttributeOverrides`, which then means manual caching of the `XmlSerializer` instances (per-type) to prevent assembly leaks, etc.